# Outer measure question.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Ok, so let $A \subset [0,1/2]$ and $B \subset (1/2,1]$ then how would I prove that the outer measure of $(A \cup B)$ is the same as outer measure of A + outer measure of B.

Answer (score 1):

Since $A\cap B=\emptyset$, so we have $\mu(A\cup B)=\mu(A)+\mu(B)-\mu(A\cap B)$ where $\mu(A\cap B)=0$.

Comment: but the outer measure isn't a measure.

Comment: You're right...but even then since $A$ and $B$ are disjoint $\exists$ disjoint open sets $U$ and $V$ such that $A\subset U$ and $B\subset V$...now take a suitable cover for $A\cup B$ and split it using $U$ and $V$.

Answer (score 0):

For outher measure $\mu^*$ we have: $$\mu^*(A\cup B)\le \mu^*(A)+\mu^*(B).      ~~~~~~~~~~(1)$$ We have to show that $$\mu^*(A\cup B)\ge  \mu^*(A)+\mu^*(B).      ~~~~~~~~~~(2)$$ 
We have:

(i) $\mu^*(A)=\inf\{ \mu(X):A \subseteq X \subseteq [0,1/2]\}$;

(ii) $\mu^*(B)=\inf\{ \mu(Y): B \subseteq Y \subseteq (1/2,1]\}$;

(iii) $\mu^*(A\cup B)=\inf\{ \mu(Z): A \cup B \subseteq Z \subseteq [0,1]\}$;

where $Z,Y,Z$ are $\mu$-measurable(equivalently, Lebesgue measurable) subsets of $[0,1]$.

For each $\mu$-measurable set $Z$ with  $A \cup B \subseteq Z \subseteq [0,1]$, we have $\mu(Z)=\mu(Z\cap [0,1/2])+ \mu(Z\cap (1/2,1])\ge \mu^*(A)+\mu^*(B).$ The later relation implies that 
$$
 \mu^*(A)+\mu^*(B)\le \inf\{ \mu(Z): A \cup B \subseteq Z \subseteq [0,1]\}=\mu^*(A\cup B).
$$